# How to add different size of local images in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

For example I can generate different drawable in android. In the same way how to generate the images in Ionic for both android and IOS. Ionic document is only mentioned with generating ICON and SPLASH SCREEN. How can I add other local images In the same way

Answer (score 0):

Other images can just be placed in the www folder, they will be resized by the webview component where the app runs in.

Comment: It should be inside www/img folder and also can it be in any format like .png or .svg?

Comment: I personally always use .jpg as this is mostly used in html